# Determining if two strings are anagrams of each other

Tags: java, strings

Is this code a good solution for the question, or is there a better way to do it?

```
package ArraysAndStrings;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class anagram{

    private boolean isAnagram = false;

    public boolean Anagrams(String str1, String str2){

        if(str1.length() != str2.length()){
            return isAnagram;
        }

        boolean [] char_set = new boolean[256];
        boolean [] char_set1 = new boolean [256];


        for(int i =0;i<str1.length();i++){

            int val1 = str1.charAt(i);
            int val2 = str2.charAt(i);

            char_set[val1] = true;
            char_set1[val2] = true;
        }

        if(Arrays.equals(char_set, char_set1)){
            isAnagram = true;
        }


        return isAnagram;

    }


    public static void main(String [] args){

        anagram ang = new anagram();

        System.out.println(ang.Anagrams("mary","army"));


    }

}
```

Comment: The code is wrong: it says that "mmary" and "armyy" are anagrams.

Comment: @vnp Given that the code includes a "test case", and that the author appears to be unaware of the bug, I would suggest that you write that as an answer.

Comment: One (fairly) efficient way to do the job is to sort the characters in each string, then compare the results. The two are anagrams if and only if the results are equal.

Comment: Please do not edit the code in your review. See [what you may do](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/31292).

Comment: Your code crashing when it sees a codepoint > 255, so it only works for less than 1% of all allocated codepoints.

Comment: As @CodesInChaos says it doesn't work with everything. `本日` ("today") and `日本` ("Japan") are anagrams but will not work with this code. If you wish to handle these cases, you should iterate the codepoints in the string rather than the chars, and use some kind of map instead of an array.

Comment: Although not quite right, the big idea here is excellent. By default most of us would probably think of sorting and comparing, avoiding the O(n^2) naive implementation, but this approach is simple, neat and fast. Thanks for sharing it and allowing others to improve on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is technically broken: it only tells that the strings are composed of the same letters. It is not enough for the strings to be anagrams. Each letter must appear the same number of times in both strings.

Making your `char_set` array integer instead of boolean you can get the correct result still in linear time:

```
    int [] counters = new int[256];
    set_counters_to_zero();
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.len(); i++) {
        counters[str1.charAt(i)]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str2.len(); i++) {
        counters[str2.charAt(i)]--;
    }
    return all_counters_are_zero();
```

Comment: @navindren Sorting is generally slower than linear time, and is usually O(n log n), where n is the number of elements to sort. Potentially a radix sort could be used here (though it is up to you to implement) to get the same linear asymptotic performance, but it will likely still be slower than this solution.

Comment: @vpn `set_counters_to_zero` is unneeded in Java, `counters` automatically gets 0-initialized. Also a potential hazard is if I give you unicode characters... in such a case, to minimize memory usage I would advise making `counters` into `Map<Character, Integer>`

Comment: I love the single-array approach, since you can then return false if any decrement goes below zero; in which case you can also return true after the second loop, and all_counters_are_zero() is unneeded. Whether checking every decrement against zero is any faster than just incrementing for all letters, decrementing for all letters, then comparing the sums of each all letter, is debatable, and would depend on what proportion of letters are likely to be 1) duplicated in each string, and 2) common between both strings. If either is low, I think checking each decrement becomes worthwhile.

Comment: @DewiMorgan `all_counters_are_zero` is still necessary, for it is possible that all of them stay positive (unless I misread your proposal).

Comment: @mleyfman Re zeroing: yes it is C++ism. Re unicode characters: you are absolutely correct. Yet  I don't think we want OP to dive right in these complications.

Comment: @vnp: after about six minutes, I tried to re-edit to add "assuming you've checked the strings have the same number of characters as a preoptimization" but it gave me the "5 minute timeout" error, so I said screw it, and ragequit because insane UI decision.
In java, string length is stored, so comparing is O(1), not O(N), so makes sense as a preoptimization.
In C and other O(N)-strlen languages, I guess fastest way is to inc a counter in each loop, then check the two are equal after the second loop. If the same, return true, else return false (as second string must've been shorter than first).

Answer (score 7):

#### Class names in Java should begin with an uppercase letter

Naming this class `anagram` is against Java's [standard naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). It should be:

```
public class Anagram {
```

#### Member variables aren't meant to hold a method's return value

```
private boolean isAnagram = false;
```

Currently you're using `isAnagram` as a member variable, which means any method inside your class could modify it. This doesn't make much sense, since you should only want the method that checks for anagrams to control it. In fact, you might even consider getting rid of this altogether.

#### Method names should begin with a lowercase letter

```
 public boolean Anagrams(String str1, String str2){
```

Again, to conform Java's naming convention, the `Anagrams` method should be called `anagrams`. But, your class is already called `Anagram`. Maybe, this method is better named as `isAnagram()`, since it is checking if two strings are anagrams.

#### Algorithmic issues

As vnp pointed out in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/116920/15221), your original algorithm only considers if both strings have the same letters, not checking if those letters occur the same number of times. Is there a better way to check for an anagram?

What if we took each string, split it into an array of all of its letters, and sorted those arrays? We would have an anagram if those arrays were identical. You added a good implementation to your post, but it still needs improvement:

```
char [] c1 = new  char [str1.length()];
char [] c2 = new char [str2.length()];

Arrays.sort(c1);
Arrays.sort(c2);
```

You create `c1` and `c2` but never store anything in them! So, your algorithm will always return `true` when passed two strings of equal length, because it's really only comparing empty arrays.

Java already gives us [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) which will take any `String` and produce a `char[]` from it, so use it, and you don't have to worry about manually creating the arrays:

```
char[] c1 = str1.toCharArray();
char[] c2 = str2.toCharArray();
```

Also, if you just return the value you're getting from `Arrays.equals()`, you won't have to keep the `isAnagram` variable around anymore.

Note that this algorithm is still incomplete for detecting anagrams, as detailed by [this comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116918/write-a-method-to-determine-if-two-strings-are-anagrams-of-each-other/116924#comment217418_116924). Additional improvements can and probably should be added.

#### Final version

```
public class Anagram {
    public boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {
        if(str1.length() != str2.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        char[] c1 = str1.toCharArray();
        char[] c2 = str2.toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(c1);
        Arrays.sort(c2);

        return Arrays.equals(c1, c2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Anagram anagram = new Anagram();
        System.out.println(anagram.isAnagram("mary","army"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than solely being upset about the senselessness of a member variable being exposed to other methods, you could also note that usage of a member variable provides other issues, like only being set when an instance of the class is created and later remembering the value it was last set to. Thus, if you first call with parameters 'mary' and 'army', it's set to true, then after that even a call with parameters 'three' and 'two' will return true.

Comment: Since subject of an anagram could be a word or a phrase, I think spaces should not be considered. Plus the equality check should not be case-sensitive. Example: "Anna Madrigal" and "A man and a girl" are anagrams of each other.

Comment: I think the method should be  static. Just like main(...).

Comment: Your final version is still buggy. Consider `äo` which is clearly not an anagram of `öa`, despite your code thinking so.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - With your example, it [returns false](http://ideone.com/vveNy6), as expected.

Comment: @Ritesh - I agree, these would be great additions. However, since the OP's original code didn't account for these possibilities, I think I'd prefer to let them figure out the implementation instead of just giving them the answer. But I'll add a note in my post citing your comment as additional ways to improve the algorithm.

Comment: @nickb You didn't copy and paste my example correctly. I used Normal Form D, your code uses form C. If you use form D correctly: http://ideone.com/nm3jM0

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Well no matter what I do I can only get the characters `LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS`, `LATIN SMALL LETTER O`, `LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS`, `LATIN SMALL LETTER A` in my editor. Feel free to suggest improvements to correct the edge case you've found.

Comment: Then use `"\u006f\u0308\u0061"` and `"\u0061\u0308\u006f"` instead.

Comment: @nickb I agree. It is up to the OP to implement additional checks as needed for space, punctuation marks, latin characters etc.  Maybe the OP should choose a suitable name to indicate the scope. For example, method name `isEnglishWordAnagram` can be used to indicate that only English words (and not phrases) are covered. Also it would be a good idea to build anagrams test data. One list is here: https://books.google.com/books?id=pVFD9fffTh8C&pg=PA40.

Answer (score 2):

This version addresses some issues with accented characters and whitespace as mentioned in comments.  E.g "\u006f\u0308\u0061", "\u0061\u0308\u006f" works as expected, as does "Anna Madrigal", "A man and a girl".

First step is to convey to lowercase and normalize the Unicode representation of accented characters to composed forms where possible. That normalization may not be correct in all situations. I'm not sure because I speak English and we don't use a lot of accented characters.  An alternative to the normalization I've done is to normalize to decomposed form and then filter out any combining marks.  Anyway, öa and äo are correctly not considered anagrams regardless of if the original encoding was decomposed or not using the method below.

We then get the sequence of characters, not including whitespace to account for cases such as "Anna Madrigal", "A man and a girl".

The comparison is done using the sorted arrays, because it is less code and optimization was not required in the question (premature optimization being evil and all), but to avoid the sorting overhead the histogram approach used in other answers can also be used after we have produced the filtered sequence of characters.  The key is coming up with some canonical representation of each string and then checking if they are the same.  Sorted characters or histogram work well for that.

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {
    String s1 = Normalizer.normalize(str1.toLowerCase(), Normalizer.Form.NFC);
    String s2 = Normalizer.normalize(str2.toLowerCase(), Normalizer.Form.NFC);

    int[] cp1 = s1.chars().filter(cp -> !Character.isWhitespace(cp)).sorted().toArray();
    int[] cp2 = s2.chars().filter(cp -> !Character.isWhitespace(cp)).sorted().toArray();

    return Arrays.equals(cp1, cp2);
}
```

[Edit]

Coming back to this years later I realize that I should have factored out a normalize() method:

```
static int [] normalize(String s) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(s.toLowerCase(), Normalizer.Form.NFC)
            .chars().filter(cp -> !Character.isWhitespace(cp))
            .sorted().toArray();
}
```

Then the orignal method becomes:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {
    return Arrays.equals(normalize(str1), normalize(str2));
}
```